# Can the raspberry pi work as a chromecast?

Tags: media-server, media

I've saw great configurations with the raspberry used as a media center but no matter what I tried I cant get it to work as a chromecast. Is there a specific distro for this purpose?

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=chromecast